# Join AVI and WMV into an AVI

Tags: macos, video, video-conversion, video-editing

I have a WMV files and two AVI files I need to concatenate into one video file as an AVI file. What the quickest and easiest way to do this on OSX?

Comment: What are your requirements regarding codecs? Why use the AVI container as output?

Comment: By "combine" do you mean simply concatenate, or do you need to do some actual video editing (cutting, effects, etc.)? Please be specific.

Comment: Simply concatenate. Its just this old video I have that is split into three parts and I want to put it on YouTube as one file rather than. MyVideo-Part1, MyVideo-Part2, etc.

Id be open to any output file format that most video players will support (not wmv)

Comment: You could join them by concatenating with ffmpeg and convert to mp4. There are several threads which discuss that on Superuser. See [this](http://superuser.com/search?q=concatenate+ffmpeg) for instance.

Comment: Im trying but it sais the directory does not exist but Im in the proper directory in terminal.

ffmpeg -i "concat:videoone.wmv|videotwo.AVI|videothree.AVI" -c copy output.mp4

Comment: You cannot copy the codecs (`-c copy`) if you have three different videos. Also, the `concat` protocol doesn't work for most containers/codecs. Please show us the output of `ffmpeg -i videoone.wmv -i videotwo.AVI -i videothree.AVI`.

Comment: It sais I need to specifiy an output. I tried add output.AVI or output.mp4 on the end of that but get:

[mpeg4 @ 0x1379200] timebase 33333/1000000 not supported by MPEG 4 standard, the maximum admitted value for the timebase denominator is 65535

Comment: i think, if it's for youtube, you could try the editor :
http://www.youtube.com/editor?feature=upload

Comment: The command does not produce any output, that was intentional. We'd just need to know some more info about your video codecs. Please [edit] your question to include the info (and don't forget you need to @-mention users so they get a reply). Thanks!